# How to isolate specific rows of a Cartesian Product - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a cartesian product and printed from the following code:

```
A = [0, 3, 5]
B = [5, 10, 15]    
C = product(A, B)

for n in C:
   print(n)
```

And we have a result of

```
(0, 5)
(0, 10)
(0, 15)
(3, 5)
(3, 10)
(3, 15)
(5, 5)
(5, 10)
(5, 15)
```

Is it possible to check the sum of each set within the cartesian product to a target value of 10? Can we then return or set aside the sets that match?

Result should be:

```
(0, 10)
(5, 5)
```

Finally, how can I count the frequency of numbers in my resulting subset to show that 0 appeared once, 10 appeared once, and 5 appeared twice? I would appreciate any feedback or guidance.

Comment: I think I clicked this by mistake. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

```
C = [p for p in product(A, B) if sum(p) == 10]
```

And to count the frequency of the numbers in the tuples, as @Amadan suggests, you can use `collections.Counter` after using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to chain the sub-lists into one sequence:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
Counter(chain.from_iterable(C))
```

which returns, given your sample input:

```
Counter({5: 2, 0: 1, 10: 1})
```

which is an instance of a dict subclass, so you can iterate over its items for output:

```
for n, freq in Counter({5: 2, 0: 1, 10: 1}).items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(n, freq))
```

Comment: And `collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*C))` for the "Finally" bit